# Laravel 4.1 + Push Queues + Error Queues

Tags: laravel-4, iron.io, push-queue

My goal is to somehow notify me if a push message fails after X attempts.

Iron.io push queues docs describe: Error Queues 
http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/#error_queues

Following the docs, I have to define an error_queue option in order to failed messages trigger a message in the specified error_queue option.

How can I define an option if push method in IronQueue.php doesn't support option argument. I see that pushRaw does support option argument.

How can I transform the following push example into a pushRaw

```
Route::get('someroute', function()
{
    Queue::push('SomeClass', array('time' => time()));
});

class SomeClass{
    public function fire($job, $data)
    {
        // do something
        $job->delete();
    }
}
```

Other ways of detecting push queues fails are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cmancre said, you can use HUD to set the error queue or you could use the API to set it: http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#update_a_message_queue

Answer (score 0):

Iron guys just rolled out an UI allowing us to set a error_error via iron admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

In case your error_queue is already firing, to complete the cycle, you need to know which message failed.

To grab the error message information, in the error_queue route just do:

```
// First we fetch the Request instance
$request = Request::instance();

// Now we can get the content from it
$content = $request->getContent();
```

Reference: http://www.codingswag.com/2013/07/get-raw-post-data-in-laravel/